# Software Updater partial upgrade?

Tags: software-center, update-manager, partial-upgrade

I just have a question about this pop up.

Should I select a partial upgrade?, will this take me out from 14.04 and upgrade me to another version of ubuntu? I mean, is this like a Distro Upgrade?. 
or is this normal update, like the security updates and so on?

See the attachment:

[image: partial upgrade will upgrade me from 14.04 to something else?]

Comment: @DnrDevil No, that is not at all what it means.

Comment: This pop up juts appeared suddenly, but I don{t wannt to move to another version besides 14.04 yet.  However, I don't know if I need to press continue to to complete all updates or what.

Comment: @dobey may be right looking closer at the wording of the updater. However I still would not do a partial install of packages. I would use the terminal and run 'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade'

Comment: what do these two do? = sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: @DnrDevil Only doing `apt-get upgrade` is a partial install of the updates. Actually, the wording is a bit confusing, because not doing the partial upgrade is actually how you end up with a partial upgrade (only some of available updates installed). Doing the `Partial Upgrade` will install the held updates as well.

Answer (score 6):

A partial upgrade is sometimes required if certain dependencies of packages changed during an update. It will not upgrade you to any other Ubuntu release, unless you've manually changed your *apt* sources to point at a newer release.

If you choose *Continue* in that dialog, you should see the list of packages to  update. Some of those may not be selectable. What *Partial Upgrade* does, is the extra bits necessary to resolve the dependencies of those packages. Usually, it means installing a new package or two.

It is perfectly safe and normal for this *Partial Upgrade* request to happen, depending on the packages you have installed.

Comment: so the bottom line is that I can go ahead and do= 'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade' without the fear of loosing anything right guys?

Comment: Yes you can use the terminal codes without the fear of loosing anything.

Comment: @KenSandoval You can use the GUI without fear of losing anything.